# How to add a timestamp to TFSBuild.proj?

Tags: logging, msbuild, timestamp, tfsbuild

I have a TFSBuild.proj file and I need to add date/time logging for statistics i.e. which parts of the builds take the most time and where can we improve the process.

The build outputs the log to BuildLog.txt. I use the following tags to get custom messages in the BuildLog.txt file, but I need to add a timestamp to each message.

```
<Message Text="Debug: BeforeGet start: StartTimeGoesHere"></Message>
<Message Text="Debug: BeforeGet end: EndTimeGoesHere"></Message>
```

Is it possible to get a timestamp in the message? Is there a MSBuild variable that gets the current datetime value? In the example above, StartTimeGoesHere will be something like "01 Jan 2001 14:10:12" and EndTimeGoesHere will be something like "01 Jan 2001 14:14:43".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need any third party support as long as you are using MSBuild 4.0.  Just use a property function within a target,

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DateTimeNow>$([System.DateTime]::Now)</DateTimeNow>
</PropertyGroup>
```

which will create the following value for $(DateTimeNow),

```
6/26/2011 9:00:27 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the MS Build Community Tasks.  It has a Time task that will give you what you want.

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

```
 <Time Format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss">
    <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="currentTime" />
 </Time>
```

You will need to setup a start and end time and you will need to be careful about where you invoke the tasks.

Comment: Useful for people on older versions of MSBuild.